# Form Validation (JavaScript), unsure why it's not working. (No errors, but messagebox doesn't appear)

Tags: javascript, html, dreamweaver

Basically, I tried to add a form to my website and when the Confirm/Submit button is clicked, the program with check if the Name & e-mail form have to the correct information, otherwise a warning will be displayed.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["form1"]["name"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("Please enter your name");
  return false;
  }
}
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["form1"]["e-mail"].value;
var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
  {
  alert("Please enter your e-mail address");
  return false;
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <h2>Form</h2>
    <p>Note: Please fill in the following fields below, thank you.</p>
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="post">
      <p>
        <label for="name">Name:</label> 
        <br />
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="e-mail">E-mail:</label>
        <br />
<input type="text" name="e-mail" id="e-mail" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="msg">Message:</label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <textarea name="msg" id="msg" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="button" name="Confirm" id="Confirm" value="Submit" />
      </p>
      <!-- end .content -->
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar2">
    <h4>&nbsp;</h4>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p><!-- end .sidebar2 --></p>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"> <img src="pics/copyright.gif" width="960" height="100" alt="footer" /></div>

<!-- end .container --></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I must add, I wasn't sure how to post my code because it keeps telling me to do such and such to it, plus I didn't post an image, because I don't have enough rep.

Comment: tough break bro. too bad you didn't give us any information at all, otherwise we might be able to help.

Comment: Could you post some code

Comment: As I said, I don't have enough rep to post an image, but if general suggestions could be given I'd appreciate it and hopefully I'll have enough rep I can post an image.

Comment: you don't need to post an image. just copy and paste your code, highlight it, then click the `{}` button. hell, you don't even need to use the code indenting, just copy and paste it. give us something man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code:

```
> <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
```

The language attribute has been deprecated for about 15 years, the type attribute is no longer required, so:

```
<script>

> function validateForm () {
>     var x=document.forms["form1"]["name"].value;
```

It is handy to pass a reference to the form from the listener so the function can be more generic. Also, named form controls are added as named properties of the form. If you have a control with a name that is the same as a form property, it will overwrite the form property so you can't access it as a property. Much better to avoid standard property names for element names and IDs, so:

```
function validateForm(form) {
    var x = form.userName.value
```

then:

```
>     if (x == null || x == "") {
```

The value of a form control is a string, so `x == null` will never be true. It's sufficient (and more suitable) to just test:

```
    if (x == "") {
```

[...]

```
> function validateForm() {
```

If you declare multiple functions with the same name, each will overwrite the previous one so you are left with just the last one. You should have a single validation function that does the checks, though each check might be a separate function.

```
> var x=document.forms["form1"]["e-mail"].value;
> var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
> var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
> if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
>   {
>   alert("Please enter your e-mail address");
>   return false;
>   }
> }
```

You can use a regular expression to check the format of the e–mail address.

```
> <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="post">
```

There generally isn't a need for ID and name attributes on a form, typically just an ID is used. For other form controls, a name is required for them to be successful, there is rarely a need for them to have an ID.

The validation function can be called from the form's submit event, so:

```
<form id="form1" onsubmit="validateForm(this);" ...>
```

[...]

```
>     <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
```

Don't use XML markup in an HTML document. And don't use element names that are the same as form attribute names as they will make the related form property inaccessible.

```
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="e-mail">E-mail:</label>
    <br />
```

Message:

If that is a submit button, then make it type submit. It doesn't need a name or ID if it's value isn't to be submitted:

```
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

So your form and code can be:

```
function validateForm(form) {
    var reUserName = /\w+/; // User name has some letters
    var reEmail = /.+@..+\..+/;  // email has some characters, @, then a dot near the end
    var passed;

    if (!reUserName.test(form.userName.value)) {
        passed = false;
        // show message for user name
    }
    if (!reEmail.test(form.eMail.value)) {
        passed = false;
        // show message for email
    }
    return passed;
}
```

Note that the e–mail validation is just what you have, which is not particularly thorough.

Then the form:

```
<form onsubmit="return validateForm(this);">
    Name: <input name="userName"><br>
    E-mail: <input name="eMail"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) It was very helpful that you went through each part.

Comment: Sadly, the code doesn't do anything, my page just refreshes and clears all fields.

Answer (score 0):

just indent your code and it should be fine, I would love to help, but without seeing the code there's not much i can do. Maybe a link to the page on your site?

Comment: That's one of the problems really, I'm not sure to indent it because I made a few indents and it continued to say I needed to indent it further